Can I use GPL 3.0 license project as library to my private project with MIT license
I'm working on a private project and considering integrating a library that is licensed under the GPL 3.0 (GNU General Public License version 3.0). However, my project itself is licensed under the MIT license, which allows for more permissive use and redistribution.
Would it be permissible to use the GPL 3.0 licensed project as a library in my private project without violating the GPL 3.0 license terms? Would the MIT license of my project conflict with the GPL 3.0 license of the library in any way? I want to ensure that my project remains closed-source while also respecting the licensing requirements of the GPL 3.0. Any insights or guidance on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your question seems to be contradictory. Your project is private, but you are also talking about distributing it.

@xuhdev project is private but distribution(.exe/.jar/.ipa/.apk) is public

@xuhdev lib is public with gpl3(which intend to be private) to use, My project is private but distribution(.exe/.jar/.ipa/.apk) is public. (Edited)

You can't - the whole point of the GPL is that it is "viral" and forces the whole program which uses any GPL code to be open source. Specifically, the GPL Section 6 requires that you distribute the Corresponding Source of the program, and Corresponding Source is defined in Section 1 to include the source code of the whole program.

will it also apply to private non-license projects (Using the GPL-3.0 library)?

The GPL applies any time you distribute material.
